# Migrating a Wordpress from a Macbook Pro to a windows laptop

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

i did export/import the db from the old macbook to the new windows laptop, then copied the whole folder from the old macbook to new laptop. i have also edited the db name and password on wp-config file.

i still have the same error message connection refused when trying to connect to the website.

Comment: Change URL in wp_option table.??

Comment: Nothing happened. How can i get the correct url

Answer (score 0):

1- Change URL from `wp_option` table that (`option_name`) is:

`siteurl` - `home`

to new `URL`

2- Fetch permalink from Setting